# Memory Allocation for float in union

Tags: c

In the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

union s1
{
    int s;
    float a;
}k;

int main()
{
    k.s=2147483640;
    printf("%f\n",k.a);
}
```

The Output I get is `nan`

While for the same code if I replace `2147483640` with 10, the output I get is `0.0000000`.

Can anyone please explain both the outputs?

Comment: You might like to read [Single-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).

Comment: What did you expect to get (and why)?

Comment: @cdarke Not pretty sure. But i had a rough idea that since both members share same memory,the output i would have got would be the same

Comment: "the output i would have got would be the same" --- just because 2 different types are represented by the same bits in memory does not mean they are interpreted as the same value.

Comment: Use `printf("%e\n",k.a);`  (e, not f).  It is more illustrative.  Even try `printf("%a\n",k.a);`  (a, not f)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone please explain both the outputs?

In C, a union is really just a value that can be interpreted in several different ways. If you put `float` data into a union and then try to read it as `int`, you'll most likely get something that doesn't make much sense because the format of `int` is very different from that of `float`. The reverse is also true: since `float` is stored in a very different format than `int`, trying to interpret `int` data as a `float` is going to give nonsense. You might get `nan`, but you might also get some value that looks valid but isn't really.

Here you're storing `int` data:

> k.s=2147483640;

And here you're trying to reinterpret that data as a `float`:

> printf("%f\n",k.a);

**Don't do that.** If you want to convert the value you stored in `k` from `int` to `float`, convert it explicitly with a cast:

```
printf("%f\n",(float)k.s);
```

Here's an example that might prove more intuitive:

```
union {
    int num;
    char[4] string;
} u;
```

Now, if we set `u.num = 1234`, then the value in `u` is going to be the *number* 1234, or `0x000004D2` in hex. You wouldn't expect that `u.string` would give you the characters `'1'`,`'2'`,`'3'`,`'4'`, right? `0x000004D2` is the characters `0x00`, `0x00`, `0x04`, `0xD2`. Going the other way, if you store the four characters `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'` and `'4'` in `u.string`, then the value in `u` will be `0x31323334`, which is 825373492 decimal, not 1234.

A union stores whatever bits you put into it, but you have to keep track of how those bits should be interpreted.

Comment: "get some value that looks valid but isn't really." --- isn't this misleading? Any bits collection is a valid float value.

Comment: So is it pretty much an "Undefined Behavior"?

Comment: @Rajsi it is not an UB. It is defined, you get exactly what is expected.

Comment: @zerkms But how will the float get interpreted in this case as both int and float share same memo?

Comment: @Rajsi any 4 bytes can be interpreted as a `float` value.

Comment: @zerkms I don't think it's misleading. The value you get will still be a `float`, but it won't be valid in the sense of being a number you'd expect. OP is storing `2147483640` in `k.s` and presumable expects to get `2147483640.0` back when accessing `k.a`, since that's what the question is about, and the point here is that that won't happen.

Comment: @Caleb it depends on what one expects: `union` by definition represents a storage shared between multiple members. It's reasonable to expect exactly that ‍♂️

Comment: @Rajsi: the point is that it will not get converted, it is just a series of bits.  Memory layout of a float consists of an optional sign, a mantissa and an exponent, totally different to the layout of an `int`.  So parts of the `int` will be the exponent and parts will be the mantissa, so the float number you end up with will not resemble the original `int`, but it will be the same bit pattern.

Comment: I know that and you know that, but the OP wouldn't have asked if they knew that.

Comment: Indeed, probably a reference to some explanation of `union` could help as well. +1 anyway :-)

Comment: `string` in `char[4] string;` hints that `string` is a C _string_.  As a terminating _null character_ is not certain, perhaps a different name?  `char_array`?

Comment: Nothing to stop you from storing a null as the last character. I didn't, which is perhaps a mistake, but that's pretty far from the point of the example.